# C - Stuck in a never ending fgets() do-while loop

Tags: c, loops, stdin, do-while, fgets

Like the title says, I can only force exit by using Ctrl-C/Z.

I get stuck in a never ending fgets() do-while loop

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int loop = 1;
    char line[255];

    printf("Running, enter a line: \n");

    do {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

        if (strcmp("exit", line) == 0){
            loop = 0;
        }

        printf("%s", line);

    } while(loop == 1);

    printf("\nNever displays...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should know definition about ```fgets()``` function. This problem will be solved easily.

Comment: I recommend [the solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/3386109).

Comment: Use ```strstr()``` at the place of ```strcmp```. It'll solve your problem.

Comment: @Lucas, `strstr` will also ignore any other incorrect content of `line` nd not only ignore the line endig. It will also return non-NULL result when comparing with `"Never exit!!!\n"` which clearly not what is the intention of the used `strcmp`.